# How do I have a meeting workspace open to the next possible occurrence of the meeting?

Tags: 2010, meeting-workspace, workspace

I have created a calendar/meeting workspace, and created a link.

I have an issue.  I need for the link to be intuitive.  I need for it to open by default to the next possible occurrence of the meeting.  For instance if it is 4/06/15, and the next occurrence is 4/13/15, that is the view the to be displayed, with all other dates still be available on the left for selection.

I created a link and removed the date information, and still cannot get it to work.

I know this has to exist, as other users have calendars that function this way, but yet for a MONTH no one, and I mean NO ONE, will tell me how they did it.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the meeting in Outlook, or from SharePoint?  If you create the recurring meeting in Outlook, each of your instances will point to the correct date.  Good Luck!

Comment: What could be a possible sharepoint solution for it?